# Commutator subgroup of $\mathbb Z_3\times S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Im trying to solve the following task:

[image]

I figured out the center is $\{(0,e),(1,e),(2,e)\}$ since i can just look at which elements commute withing the two groups.

However, im having troubles understanding how im supposed to search for the commutator subgroup efficiently. I can brute force all 18 combinations, but there must be a better way.

I am aware that the commutator subgroup is the smallest normal subgroup s.t. the quotient group is abelian. I just have no idea how to use that fact to my advantage currently.

How am i supposed to solve these kinds of problems, generally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commutator of any two pairs $(a,b),(c,d)$ is $(0,[b,d])$. So the commutator subgroup is $\{0\}\times [S_3, S_3]=\{0\}\times A_3$ where $A_3$ consists of the identity and two $3$-cycles and is the cyclic subgroup of $S_3$ of order $3$.